# SQL Query To find Train between stations

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

This is my table of a train time table I want a solution for train between stations

```
Train  Code
15609  ABC
15609  XYZ
15609  PQR  
15609  ADI  
15609  QWE   
15609  XPM   
15609  IND 
15680  ABC
15680  XYZ
15680  PQR  
15680  ADI  
15680  QWE   
15680  XPM   
15680  IND
```

For the output the user will give two inputs of codes eg: `ABC` and `XYZ`
    and the the output will be all train number having code `ABC` and `XYZ`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick. It also should perform well--no JOIN is needed.

```
SELECT
   Train
FROM
   dbo.TrainTime
WHERE
   Code IN ('ABC', 'XYZ')
GROUP BY
   Train
HAVING
   Count(DISTINCT Code) = 2
;
```

Comment: It performs better than queries that use a `JOIN`. Is there a reason you didn't choose it?

Answer (score 4):

I think what you want is something like this

```
select Train from mytable where Code = 'ABC'
intersect
select Train from mytable where Code = 'XYZ'
```

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fb99b/2)

Comment: I'm confused how the query that will not perform as well was selected and voted up more? This query requires a `JOIN`, which is not necessary. Compare [execution plans at SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4f345/1)! I promise you that on a large table this will be a very significant difference. Plus, this cannot as easily be generalized to an arbitrary number of stations--the query has to change length drastically.

Comment: While I could (partially) agree on generalizing query, I think that my query is a little bit more readable. 
And performance is depends on indexes you have on your table. If you have indexes done right, performance is equal on both queries.

I've tried both queries on ~200000 rows with indexes and have (reads:12, duration:0 on my query and reads:16, duration:1) on your so it's equal for me. And I'm always write query with indexes in mind.

If you don't have indexes, your query performs better, but table scan is bad idea on large number of rows anyway.

Comment: Anyway, here's my +1 for you answer, Erik.

Comment: Fair enough on the indexes. That is a good point. Two seeks is two seeks. If a scan is required, only then do our two queries start to be differentiated in performance. However,  my comments about query modification still hold.

Answer (score -1):

Well, this is quite, maybe too simple:

```
select distinct [Train] from mytable 
where code = 'ABC' or code = 'XYZ'
```

Let me know if I misunderstood somthing.

Comment: It must not have OR i need both code together having common train number

Comment: Oh I see, sorry. Then I suggest to use something like Roman Pekar proposed below.